# Android Studio org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Tags: android-studio

[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYXH1.png)

[My Build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3xn8.png)

Have tried deleting .gradle file and reinstalling android studio

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn about the good practices of asking questions in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents here but I get this error when I put an apostrophe in my project name.